# Having issues with python for loops

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

So apparently I'm supposed to make this question relevant to all people, but that's pretty hard to do as it has to do with a VERY specific problem.

I'm using an online tutorial program to learn python (V2 I believe) and the exorcise I'm on wants me to quote:

1. Write a *for*-loop that iterates over *start_list* and *.append()s* each number squared *(x ** 2)* to *square_list*.
2. Then sort *square_list*.

I'm still trying to wrap my head around lists and loops so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious

```
`
start_list = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
square_list = []
square_list.append(start_list)
# Your code here!
for square_list in square_list:
    square_list.sort()
print square_list`
```

above is the script I'm using. I left out the part about squaring as I'm still trying to figure out how I'm supposed to do that. It *does* however, print all 5 numbers in order. Despite this, I keep getting the error message that says "Make sure not to modify start_list." I don't understand what I'm don't to modify it.

Comment: You're appending all of "start_list" into "square_list". in fact, you'll want to iterate over the items in "start_list", and append each item (after squaring it) to square_list individually. I assume you wanted a general pointer, but i'd be happy to write it out if necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't follow the instructions.

> Write a for-loop that iterates over start_list and .appends()'s each number squared to square_list.

The following meets this criteria:

```
for number in start_list:
    square_list.append(number ** 2)
```

You iterate over start_list. Each item will be "number" exactly once. You square it and add it to square_list.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to append a list object to the list `square_list`. That's not what you want in there. You need to append the contents of `start_list` instead. To append the items, use the loop like that:

```
for i in start_list:
    square_list.append(i**2)
```

This code will add the square of each element to the `square_list`. Then, *outside the loop*, call the `.sort()` method on the `square_list` to sort it like that:

```
square_list.sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
start_list = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
square_list = []
for num in start_list:
    square_list.append(num ** 2)
print sorted(square_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehensions is a better idea here, you run the same for and create a new list out of the existing items, yet you won't need to complicate your life with append operations. You iterate over the whole list and that's it.

```
print([item ** 2 for item in start_list])
```

**Edit:** For is a must:

```
result_list = []
for item in start_list:
    result_list.append(item**2)
print(sorted(result_list))
```

Comment: As @Anon is doing an interactive tutorial I believe this solution may not work. He may specifically require a for-loop for the solution.

Comment: The assignment is to write a for-loop, not a list comprehension.